# decrypt ,md5 encrypt data in react native

Tags: react-native, cryptography, md5, password-hash, cryptographic-hash-function

I want to know, how can I decrypt, md5 encrypt data in react native. May you help me. I can't fine any tutorial in web. I added md5 library for encrypt but I can't decrypt that cod. If you know about encrypt too, please explain that. How can I use in react native cod. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is not an encryption algorithm! It is a message-digest algorithm used as a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashish) function.

[Cryptographic hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) functions are one-way, deterministic, compression functions that behave randomly.

- One-way means no inverse function exists,
- deterministic means the same inputs result in the same output,
- compression means the input size can be any length but the output size is fixed by the hash function. MD5 has a 128-bit digest size.
- Random means the hash function output is unpredictable before computing.

The MD5 pre-image resistance theoretically is broken bu not practically. Instead of the generic preimage attack with 2<sup>128</sup> complexity, there is an [attack that requires 2<sup>123.4</sup> complexity](https://doi.org/10.1007%2F978-3-642-01001-9_8). MD5, however, is not practically broken. You cannot reach the 123-bit search space in a meaningful time. Consider the collective power of BitCoin miners; in 2020/1/17 they [reached 126.1314 Exahashes per second,](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-hashrate.html) that makes

- 2<sup>67</sup> SHA256 double hashes in a second, and
- 2<sup>92</sup> SHA256 double hashes in a year. So you need 2<sup>21</sup> years with that power.

However, you can find [collisions](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/%7Eselinger/md5collision/) for MD5. There are two good libraries two produce collisions;  [corkami](https://github.com/corkami/collisions/blob/master/README.md) or [hashclash](https://github.com/cr-marcstevens/hashclash/blob/master/README.md)

For encryption, use AES or ChaCha20 with proper modes like AES-GCM or AES-GCM-SIV and ChaCha20-Poly1305 bot provides authenticated encryption that you will get Confidentiality, Integrity, and authentication.